# White space at the top of the accordion list in Framework7

Tags: android, accordion, html-framework-7

I am using Framework7 to create a static App. So when I am trying to insert an accordion list into the page content section an unnecessary white space is generated at the top. I am using the android material theme. As per my analysis it has something to do with the Toolbar Div, but I can't pinpoint the exact cause.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can I see your code?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you put the css `toolbar-fixed` to your page.

To solved this problem, remove the class `toolbar-fixed` from your page. Usually it is located on 
`<div data-page="autocomplete" class="page toolbar-fixed page-on-center">`

Answer (score 0):

Earlier I was commenting out the Toolbar Div for Android Material theme, but when I completely removed/deleted the Toolbar div from the index.html file, the issue got resolved.